# php code two response not printing

Tags: php, post, response

I have tried getting the value of player id from my table barrel_user using post request my only problem is two response is not working but if I give only one it works

```
        $customer_query="SELECT player_id FROM barrel_user where     phone_number='$phone_number'";
$fetchresult=mysqli_query($conn,$customer_query);

  if(mysqli_num_rows($fetchresult)>0)
{
  while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchresult)){

//  $response=$rows;


  if ($fetchresult) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        //$response["player_id"]= $player_id;

            $player_id= $rows['player_id']; 
              $response=$rows;
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
    }

  // $response["success"] = 'User Exists';
  }
}
```

above is my php code for a post request

I am not getting this value 
      $response["success"] = 1;

but I am getting the value of player_id

note:- the code works fine and if I remove $response=$rows  I am getting the message success=1

Comment: how to get both message?

Comment: I want success=1 and player_id

Comment: First of all your code is sensitive voor SQL Injection. the `$response=$rows` means that $repsonse will be $rows;  but $rows doesn't contain the success. You can use the `array_merge` method to combine both

Comment: just remove `$response=$rows;` line for that, you are overriding value of response

Comment: so what shut I use instead of that??

Comment: You need to use array_push

Comment: Try `$response[]=$rows;`

Comment: I am getting{"success":1,"0":{"player_id";"1"}}

Comment: Initially you are pushing 1 to $response it will treat as an array,

after execute this ,
$response=$rows;   it will replace the  $response["success"] = 1; to $rows

so if you wants this both use this,

$response[]=$rows;

OR use json_encode(),

json_encode(array('response'=>1,'row'=>$row))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$response=array();
$customer_query="SELECT player_id FROM barrel_user where     phone_number='$phone_number'";
$fetchresult=mysqli_query($conn,$customer_query);

  if(mysqli_num_rows($fetchresult)>0)
{
  while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchresult)){

  if ($fetchresult) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        //$response["player_id"]= $player_id;

            $player_id= $rows['player_id']; 
              $response[]=$player_id;
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
    }

  }
}
```